# Pushing to Gitlab merge-requests remote does not recognize changes from rebase

Tags: git, gitlab

Me and my coworker, John, are collaborating on an upstream project P using Gitlab. We have both forked P, and in my fork, I have two branches: B1 and B2. B1 is essentially an older version of B2, but the two branches have diverged.

John wants to make a merge request to my fork from his branch C1, which is branched off B1. His merge request initially targeted B1, but I asked him to retarget it to B2; he did that, but now there are a bunch of extra commits that I don't want, as B1 and B2 have diverged.

To make things easier on Jake, I decided that I would checkout his merge request locally and retarget it myself, then push the changes back, so he would not have to do anything. I ran the following commands:

1. `git fetch origin refs/merge-requests/17/head:refs/merge-requests/17/head`
2. `git checkout refs/merge-requests/17/head`
3. `git checkout -b mr17`
4. `git rebase B2`
5. `git push origin refs/merge-requests/17/head`

However, instead of updating his open merge request, as I thought it would, the push succeeded, but said "Everything up-to-date". This surprised me, as I had just rebased the branch. I checked .git/refs/merge-requests/17/head and found that it is pointing at the old (pre-rebase) commit hash.

I'm guessing I screwed something up here, but I don't really understand what. Can I edit .git/refs/merge-requests/17/head to point at the *new* (post-rebase) commit hash? Or do I have to start over with different steps?

Answer (score 0):

Your `push` command is missing which *local* branch to push:

```
git push origin mr17:refs/merge-requests/17/head
```

Besides that, I don't think the result is what you are expecting. Your rebased branch will still contain all commits from B1 (which were present in the original merge request). You will need to perform an interactive rebase and remove those commits from the rebase script. Alternatively, use the full invocation of `git rebase` (before your initial rebase-attempt):

```
git rebase --onto B2 B1 mr17
```

Answer (score 0):

You should both work on the fork and push to the fork's branch, not the `refs/heads/merge_requests/...` branch. The merge request refs are generally only internal to GitLab and should not be used directly. The only time you should use them is to pull the changes from a merge request to test. Pushes to these refs would be overwritten by pushes to the source branch.